# R function that takes a data frame and a list of columns then for each of those columns adds binarized variables to the original data frame

Tags: r, function

This function does not work but if I try the code without making it a function it works.  I am not able to understand why.
Data can be found here: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/gapminderDataFiveYear.csv

```
df.data<- read.csv("D:/My R project/data/gapminderDataFiveYear.csv")

namearray<- c(levels(unlist(df.data[, "continent"])))

binarycoladd<- function(a1, a2) {

 al1<- length(a2)
  al2<- nrow(a1)

  for (i in 1:al1) {

cname<- paste("binary", a2[i], sep = "_")

a1[cname]<- NA

    for (j in 1:al2) {
      a1[j,cname] = ifelse (a1[j,"continent"] == a2[i], 1, 0)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: after making this function binarycoladd, if i use it in R as binarycoladd(df.data, namearray), nothing happens.

Comment: Are you calling the function `binarycoladd`?

Comment: Thank you for the answers.  Could you also please tell me why what i am trying to do does not work?  I am a beginner and hence would really like to know.

Comment: @chiragkadian The main reason is: you are *not* returning the dataframe from your function ... and to save the result of the function call the call should be `... <- binarycoladd(df.data, namearray)`

Comment: df.data<- read.csv("D:/My R project/data/gapminderDataFiveYear.csv")
namearray<- c(levels(unlist(df.data[, "continent"])))
binarycoladd<- function(a1, a2) {
  al1<- length(a2)
  al2<- nrow(a1)
  
  for (i in 1:al1) {
    cname<- paste("binary", a2[i], sep = "_")
    a1[cname]<- NA
    
    for (j in 1:al2) {
      a1[j,cname] = ifelse (a1[j,"continent"] == a2[i], 1, 0)
    }
  }
}

abc<-binarycoladd(df.data, namearray)

I tried saving the result of the function, however the object abc is NULL in the environment.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, i understand now why it was not working.  This code now works:  binarycoladd<- function(a1, a2) {
  al1<- length(a2)
  al2<- nrow(a1)
  
  for (i in 1:al1) {
    cname<- paste("binary", a2[i], sep = "_")
    a1[cname]<- NA
    
    for (j in 1:al2) {
      a1[j,cname] = ifelse (a1[j,"continent"] == a2[i], 1, 0)
    }
  }
return(a1)
  }          df.empty<- data.frame()
df.empty<- binarycoladd(df.data, namearray)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a correct version of your function:

```
df.data <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/gapminderDataFiveYear.csv")

namearray <- as.character(levels(df.data$continent))

binarycoladd <- function(a1, a2) {
  for (cn in a2) {
    cname <- paste0("binary_", cn)
    a1[cname] <- (a1$continent == cn)
  }
  return(a1)
}

binarycoladd(df.data, namearray)
```

(Do not forget to save the result `... <- binarycoladd(...)`)
Here is a version how I would do it:

```
binarycols <- function(x) {
  xlev <- levels(x)
  M <- sapply(xlev, '==', x)
  colnames(M) <- paste0("binary_", xlev)
  return(M)
}

cbind(df.data, binarycols(df.data$continent))
```

BTW:
if you want to use `$continent` in a regression model the logical dummy variables are internally generated by the function `lm()` - so there is no need to generate them explicitly:

```
df.data <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/gapminderDataFiveYear.csv")
summary(lm(lifeExp ~ continent + year, data=df.data))
```

Comment: Thank you so much sir.  You are a champ!